# How to grab and return a Div with its Id included

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seems like a super simple question but I can't find an answer.

I'm grabbing a DIV "user-entry"

```
var $user = $('#user-entry');
```

HTML:

```
<div id="user-entry">

<table style="border: none; width: 100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left">
                        @Html.Label("Hello World")
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now I want to append this to another div `<div id="role"></div>`.
That's what JQuery append(), appendTo(), prepend(), prependTo() functions are for. Great!

My problem is that when used the DIV is being added without the actuall DIV name.
If example run:

```
            var $user= $('#user-entry');
            $($user.html()).appendTo('#role');
```

Then my table is being properly appended to the "role" but the user DIV itself doesn't show.

Instead of:

```
<div id="role">
   <div id="user-entry">
      <table style="border: none; width: 100%">
     </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

I end up with:

```
<div id="role">
      <table style="border: none; width: 100%">
     </table>
</div>
```

How can I capture and return a div with its name Included ?

Comment: Wouldn't this cause multiple elements to have the same ID?

Comment: What's the actual line of code that isn't working?

Comment: I"ll remove $user.remove() after it correctly appears where it has to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it

```
$('#user-entry').appendTo('#role');
```

`$($user.html()).appendTo('#role');` creates a copy of the elements inside `<div id="user-entry">` and appends them to `<div id="role">`

Answer (score 3):

because by using `html` method you are only appending the contents of the div, try this:

```
$('#user-entry').clone().appendTo('#role')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52bxz/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#user-entry').appendTo('#role');
```

Or if you want to clone it try:

```
$('#user-entry').clone().appendTo('#role')
```